# Give an example or state it's impossible

Tags: real-analysis

A sequence of closed **bounded** (not necessarily nested) intervals $I_1,I_2,I_3,\dots$ with the property that $\bigcap_{n=1}^NI_n\neq\emptyset$ for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, but $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n=\emptyset$.

I tried to come up with some examples but failed. One example I came up with is a "shifting" sequence of closed bounded intervals, $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ with $(a_n)=(1,2,3,4,5,\dots,N,N+1,\dots)$ and $(b_n)=(N,N+1,N+2,\dots)$. Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^NI_n =\{N\}$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n=\emptyset$. But clearly it's wrong...

Comment: What are your thoughts ?

Comment: Hint: They cannot be nested…

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: To comment on your example, you can't let the intervals depend on $N$. That's backwards. You must first give a fixed collection of intervals which do not change, and then you show that the intersection is non-empty for any $N$.

Comment: I see why I can't use $N$, but if I let $M$ be any natural number and replace $N$ with $M$, it's still wrong. Is it even possible to come up with an example?

Comment: Hint: suppose this were possible. Then $J_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}I_k$ is a **decreasing** sequence of nonempty closed bounded sets. What can you say about $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n$?

Comment: @Bungo Could you explain why it's a decreasing sequence?

Comment: $J_{n+1} = I_{n+1} \cap J_n \subseteq J_n$

Comment: @Bungo Thank you! And then since it's decreasing, can I apply the Nested Interval property to prove that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: The nested interval property will prove that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n \neq \emptyset$. Then, do you see how $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ are related?

Comment: Should they equal to each other?

Comment: Yes, they are equal. You can show this formally by showing that they are subsets of each other.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, there exists no such sequence. Suppose that each $I_n$ is a closed, bounded interval and that for each $n$, we have $\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}I_k \neq \emptyset$. Define $J_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}I_k$. Then:

- $J_n$ is closed, because it is an intersection of closed sets.
- $J_n$ is bounded, because it is contained in $I_1$.
- $J_n$ is nonempty by assumption.
- $J_n$ is an interval, because a nonempty intersection of finitely many intervals is an interval (easy proof by induction).
- $(J_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a decreasing nested sequence, because for each $n$, we have $J_{n+1} = I_{n+1} \cap J_n \subseteq J_n$.

By the nested interval theorem, we conclude that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n$ is nonempty. But you can easily verify that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ (show that they are subsets of each other), so $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ is nonempty.